# Set images left-aligned in Typora

Tags: css, markdown

By default, Typora set all the images center-aligned.

[image]

I searched through the `github.css` but did not found `img`.

```
$ grep img "/Users/me/Library/Application Support/abnerworks.Typora/themes/github.css"
#return no matches
```

How could I set images left-aligned?

Comment: Could it be another CSS file like: https://github.com/typora/typora-theme-gallery/blob/gh-pages/assets/css/typora-wiki.css ? Let me know the web page URL you are working with.

Comment: search through but fail to find it in local `$ find / -regex ".*typora-wiki.css
→ " 2>/dev/null  #return nothon.` @ManojKumar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit CSS file of your theme.

Go to **`File > Preference`** or press **`Ctrl+Comma`**. In Themes, click **`Open Theme Folder`**.

[image]

Open the CSS file of your theme. For example, I'm using *Github* theme.

[image]

Search for `img {}` in CSS file. In `github.css`, I didn't find any `img {}`. If you don't find `img {}`, you can write one. Then, set the `display` and `align-items` as below.

```
img {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```

Alignment before applying above CSS properties:

[image]

Alignment after applying above CSS code:

[image]

**Note:** (Sometimes but not necessarily) In some conditions, while editing the file, if cursor is somewhere between the images or images link, it can show the image in center temporarily. But if you change the position of cursor away from the images, it results well.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 11):

Found this ridiculously simple but maybe unstable solution by accident: put a space character after the image. Actually, any character works, so to make it more visible I've put the letter 's' after the image in this example:

[image]

Tested in Typora version 0.9.93 (Beta).

Comment: I think this is the best solution and not hacky at all. In fact adding a character (e.g. a simple space) after the image, informs Typora (or any other editor per se) that this image is supposed to be in a paragraph, and paragraphs are always aligned linguistically by default (depending if the language of the text is left-to-right or right-to-left). This is in most case the desired outcome.

Answer (score 2):

According to the official document [here](https://support.typora.io/Images/), to left aligned a img by adding following code in github.css or yourTheme.css:

```
p .md-image:only-child{
    width: auto;
    text-align: left;
}
```